# Team Foundation Add-in - Using VBA to 'Get Work Items'

Tags: excel, vba, tfs, automation

I'm using the Team Foundation add-in for Excel 2016.

On the 'Team' tab on the ribbon, there is a button called 'Get Work Items'. With this feature, I can manually input IDs and it will pull the record from TFS directly into the worksheet.

To avoid having to do this manually, I would like to use VBA to input a list of IDs into the 'Get Work Items' feature.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

James

Comment: Why you have to use the VBA? you can create a work item query in TFS to get the list of work items you needed, then open the query in Excel, then do further actions...

Comment: Hi Andy. That's what I normally do but, going forward, I will be unable to do this. The problem is, the list of work items I want to look at will vary and I need a way to take this list in Excel and use the 'Get Work Items' to extract them from TFS. Is there a way to do this with VBA?

Comment: Sorry, no any experience on this, it's an excel issue...